# why it does not start from the first line of array?

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop

code:

```
#!/bin/bash

aa=(1 2 3 4)

for i in "${aa[@]}";do
echo "${aa[$i]}"
done

exit 0
```

it will prints out:

```
2
3
4
```

i dont think theres an error in my code, I already double checked it with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) too.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217210/discussion-on-question-by-ahiung-lim-why-it-does-not-start-from-the-first-line-o).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop iterates over the array's *values*, not its *indices*. It'll be clearer if you make the array values strings:

```
aa=(foo bar baz quux)

for entry in "${aa[@]}";do
    echo "$entry"
done
```

Notice how I got rid of the `aa[$i]` lookup and just print the variable directly. This prints:

```
foo
bar
baz
quux
```

If you want to iterate over the indices add `!`:

```
for i in "${!aa[@]}";do
    echo "${aa[$i]}"
done
```

Or use a C-style loop:

```
for ((i = 0; i < "${#aa[@]}"; i++)); do
    echo "${aa[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: small question, what is ! in ${!..}? what i already know is #="number of" and @="item"

Comment: It doesn't really have a name, it's just the thing you type to get array indices. It's the "give me array indices instead of values" operator, so to speak. There are several other uses for `!` but they're not really related; there's no unifying concept.